# Color Splash Screen - UWP app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp, uwp-xaml

Is it possible to set a color of our choice for SplashScreen or do I have to use an already defined color?

For example, I want to use a green (MediumSpringGreen), but wanted to change the transparency of this color, making it slightly lighter.

Answer (score 22):

You can customize this in the package.appxmanifest file.

1. Open the file.
2. Select the *Visual Assets* tab.
3. Select *Splash Screen.*
4. Enter a hexadecimal color value in *Splash screen background.*

[image]